# Why is x undefined in inner scope?

Tags: javascript

In the code below

```
var x = 1;

(function () {
  console.log(x);
  var x = 2;
}());
```

Why is it that when console.log(x), x is undefined?

Comment: @WolfOfWallstreet So you want after you console.log(x); to get number 2 right ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Variable hoisting.  The actual code is executed like this.

```
var x = 1;
(function() {
    var x; // x = undefined
    console.log(x);
    x = 2;
})();
```

Edit: On Mr Lister's advice, a bit on variable hoisting.  From MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

"Variable declarations, wherever they occur, are processed before any code is executed. The scope of a variable declared with var is its current execution context, which is either the enclosing function or, for variables declared outside any function, global."

Comment: Can you explain to the OP what variable hoisting is and why `var x=1; function whatever() {console.log(x);}` does work?

Comment: I know they can look it up elsewhere, but if would be nice if answers here were self-contained.

Comment: @TBWill4321 This code when I do it.It gives undefined!

Comment: @EndritShala Yes, the question was not "How do I make this code...", it was asking for an explanation of why the code was acting the way it did.  The code I posted is identical, just expanded version showing variable hoisting.

Comment: @TbWill4321 Oh okay I didn't understand the question because I'm new to english so I didn't understand I tought he asked that he needed to get in console number 2.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the compiler, even if you initiate a var down below the code, the compiler send it to the top, just like `var x;`, so it first initiate as undefined "x" before running console.log, that's why is such a good practice to initate all vars you're going to use first thing in the function, so these mistakes won't happen.